# List "contains" function in Z3

Tags: z3, smt

Given a typical list datatype:

```
(declare-datatypes (X)(
  (Lst
    (nil)
    (insert
      (head X)
      (tail Lst)))))
```

I'm trying to create a function that returns whether a given element is in a given list. It looks like I have to use an uninterpreted function. I've tried different approaches without success. For example:

```
(declare-fun is-in-lst ((Int)(Lst Int)) Bool)

(assert (forall((elem Int)(lst (Lst Int)))
  (=
    (is-in-lst elem lst)
    (and
      (is-insert lst)
      (or
        (= elem (head lst))
        (is-in-lst elem (tail lst)))))))

(declare-const l1 (Lst Int))

(assert (is-in-lst 6 l1))
(assert (is-in-lst 5 l1))
```

Is this doable in Z3? If so, what would be the best way to address the problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest SMTLib standard allows for recursive definitions. Also `List` is predefined in Z3, so you don't need to define it yourself. You can code your function as:

```
(define-fun-rec elem ((e Int) (l (List Int))) Bool
   (ite (= l nil) false (or (= e (head l)) (elem e (tail l)))))

(declare-const l1 (List Int))
(assert (elem 6 l1))
(assert (elem 5 l1))

(check-sat)
(get-value (l1))
```

For this, z3 responds:

```
sat
((l1 (let ((a!1 (insert 6 (insert 4 (insert 7 (insert 5 nil))))))
  (insert 0 (insert 1 (insert 3 (insert 2 a!1)))))))
```

You might have to get a recent version of Z3 from their nightly builds, as support for recursive-functions is rather new and thus the latest official release (4.6.0) may or may not work with this. (You can get nightly builds from https://github.com/Z3Prover/bin/tree/master/nightly.)